# Why does this simple function not return a value?

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to write a function that returned a collection, but could not seem to get that to work, so I tried something very simple.  I must be doing something really dumb.

When I run temp1, in the following code , I expect to see this:

```
afunc value = 4
temp1 afunc = 4
```

but what I get is this:

```
afunc value = 4
temp1 afunc = 0
```

.

```
Function aFunc() As Integer
  Dim theValue As Integer
  Dim retValue As Integer
  theValue = 4
  Debug.Print "afunc value = " & theValue
  retValue = theValue
End Function

Sub temp1()
  Debug.Print "temp1 afunc = " & aFunc()
End Sub
```

I am sure this is something very basic, but I don't see what it is.

Comment: You never set `aFunc` to a value in the function so it returns 0. I think you want `aFunc = theValue`.

Comment: ok, thanks ... never saw that in the doc ... seemed like the returned value would be the last statement executed.

Comment: That's a terrible doc then XD in VBA, a function returns itself.

Comment: @findwindow I guess when I go back and look , it does say that .. i had been trying return blah , but it complained about that.  You "answered first" if you want to enter an answer (with a little explanation) i will accept it.

Comment: Oh ok. I am just happy to help ^_^ You are welcome to accept Batman's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the end of `aFunc()`, add `aFunc = theValue` instead of `retValue = theValue`.